# Android Rect width and height differs from original dimensions

Tags: java, android

I was tracing a problem of why Rect.intersects function did not work in my Android application and found out that one of my rectangles have an incorrect width and height.

```
ImageView tt = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tt);
Rect newInRect = new Rect(421, tt.getTop(), tt.getRight(), tt.getBottom());
Log.d("Size comparison", String.format("getRight %d, getLeft: %d | Width: %d, Height: %d", tt.getRight(), tt.getLeft(), newInRect.width(), newInRect.height()));
```

The output is: "Size comparison: getRight 296, getLeft: 144 | Width: -124, Height: 152"

Don't getRight() and getBottom() functions stand for width and height?
Why do they return different values? Which one is correct?
My intention is to make a Rect exactly the same size as an ImageView called tt but with a different X coordinate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, look into the implementation of `Rect`:

```
 /**
 * @return the rectangle's width. This does not check for a valid rectangle
 * (i.e. left <= right) so the result may be negative.
 */
public final int width() {
    return right - left;
}

/**
 * @return the rectangle's height. This does not check for a valid rectangle
 * (i.e. top <= bottom) so the result may be negative.
 */
public final int height() {
    return bottom - top;
}
```

Your just comparing wrong values. Try to compare width and heigth in both cases (`Rect`'s).

Answer (score 0):

To get the width and height:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = tt.getLayoutParams();
int h = layoutParams.height;
int w = layoutParams.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getLeft()`, `getRight()`, `getBottom()` and `getTop()` return values relative to the parent, not screen coordinates.